# Facing problem in JavaScript function execution

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple Shopping List App in which user can Add, Delete and mark the task done when completed. So far, I am able to add the task but facing problem in executing the done and delete functions. I am getting an error because when I execute it, the done and delete buttons are not there but what should I do to fix it?

```js
var inp = document.getElementById("form");
var button = document.getElementById("click");

//Create List Function with Done and Delete Buttons
function addVal() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("list");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  var done = document.createElement("button");
  var del = document.createElement("button");

  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
  span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inp.value));
  done.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Done"));
  del.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete"));
  li.appendChild(span);
  li.appendChild(done);
  li.appendChild(del);
  done.setAttribute("class", "doneBut");
  del.setAttribute("class", "delBut");
  ul.appendChild(li);
  inp.value = "";
}

//Get Input Length
function checkLength() {
  return inp.value.length;
}

//Run function on Button Click
function onButtonClick() {
  if (checkLength() > 0) {
    addVal();
  }
}

//Run function on Enter Keypress
function onEnter(event) {
  if (checkLength() > 0 && event.which === 13) {
    addVal();
  }
}

//Trigger Events
button.addEventListener("click", onButtonClick);
inp.addEventListener("keypress", onEnter);

//Done and Delete Button Functions
var doneButton = document.getElementsByClassName("doneBut");
var deleteButton = document.getElementsByClassName("delBut");

function doneTask() {
  doneButton.parentNode.classList.add("done");
}

function delTask() {
  deleteButton.parentNode.classList.add("delete");
}

doneButton.addEventListener("click", doneTask);
deleteButton.addEventListener("click", delTask);
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Task..." id="form" />
<button id="click">Add Task</button>
<h2>List:</h2>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Please Help.

Comment: Please add your code on this site

Comment: @JackBashford I have made some edits to the question. Can it be re-opened now? I am new to the community and I don't know how it works that's why I am commenting here.

Comment: it will only be reopened if the community deems it so - each person (including me) can only cast one reopen vote for each post.

Comment: I've voted to reopen, now that the question contains code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the code tries to add events before the buttons exist. The buttons don’t exist until the `addVal` function gets called. Since `addVal` is not being called before the you try to add your event handlers, the `getElementById` returns null, and you attempt to add an event listener to null.

Additionally it looks like you’re planning to add multiple done and delete buttons. That wouldn’t normally be a problem, except you’re referencing them by ID, and IDs **MUST** be unique. You’ll need to switch this to a class or an attribute, since you’ll need one per item in the shopping cart.

You’ll probably want to look into event delegation, so that you can add your events once to the page before any buttons exist. https://javascript.info/event-delegation

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely because your script is running before your code is running. Add the `<script>` tags just before the closing `</body>` tag to fix it:

```
<script>/* Your code here */</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place this in a `window.onload` function, or run it in a function inside of the body tag's `onload`. Those elements don't exist yet when the script is run:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var inp = document.getElementById("form");
    var button = document.getElementById("click");
    button.addEventListener("click", onButtonClick);
    inp.addEventListener("keypress", onEnter);
}
```